# How to gain initial reputation on Reddit?

Tags: reddit

I'm new to Reddit and I'm trying to contribute to discussions. However, all my posts and comments are being removed due to having insufficient karma. I tried to like posts and comments, write my own posts and comments in different subreddits but nothing has helped. All my posts were removed and I still have 1 karma on my profile. Is there a way to break that vicious cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of struggling I found the solution:

**You need to post on [r/FreeKarma4U](https://www.reddit.com/r/FreeKarma4U/).** It's a subreddit specifically designed for those who have problems gaining initial karma on reddit. This will allow you to get enough karma to make posts in other subreddits.